# get id custom tables on current page

Tags: pages, id

i will get id on current page.

```
<?php 
    $hasil = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,bab,tema FROM $tabel ORDER BY bab ASC");
    foreach ($hasil as $bab) :
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $bab->bab;?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $bab->tema;?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_path('lks')).'?id='.$bab->id;?>">Kerjakan</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

then urls showing :

```
localhost/wordpress/lks?id=2
```

and works on after page if i call $_GET['id'].

but i will urls showing :

```
localhost/wordpress/lks/2
```

and i change permalink

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_path('lks')).'/'.$bab->id;?>
```

Dont work on after page if i call $_GET['id'].

How can i get id 2 the url on after page?

or there are other ideas that I can get the id with the url?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your question better. It is hard to understand your problem.

Comment: @toscho my question is edit..sorry bad my english.

Comment: @s_ha_dum if i call `get_permalink($bab->id);` it's same if i call on page don't after page.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question but if `$bab->id` is the ID in the `$wpdb->post` table then [`get_permalink($bab->id);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) will give you the permalink for the page.

If you are trying to get the ID of the page after you click those links, try:

```
echo $post->ID;
// or...
$pobj = get_queried_object();
echo $pobj->ID;
```

Again, it is very hard to tell what you are asking so I am making a series of guesses.